# Zabbix монитоинг интерфейса fa0/0

Tags: интерфейс, маршрутизатор, zabbix, cisco

Добрый день. Я новичек в сис. администрировании.Поэтому прошу не ругаться =
 Настраиваю в заббиксе мониторинг загрузки интерфейса fa0/0 и потери пакетов на нем 
Подскажите как реализовать? В гугле был, вот что сделал: 
[image: настройка]

и вроде как по snmp он видит его но почему не поддерживается эллемент данных? что я делаю не так? 
[image: ошибка]
Как настроить мониторинг интерфейса fa0/0 на нагрузку и потерю пакетов через Заббикс

Гугл уже перерыл, надежда только на вас

Comment: Если навести мышкой на красный крестик на последнем скриншоте, какую ошибку показывает Zabbix?

Comment: говорит, что не правильные параметры, это я итак знаю)
дело в другом,  хотелось-бы хотя-бы услышать четко и понятно как настроить именно fa0/0 на потерю пакетов 
понимаю, что надо как-то узнать OID этого интерфейса. но доступа к комутатору нет. доступа к серверу с заббиксом нет, есть только доступ к самому заббиксу. 
что я имею: 
ip маршрутизатра,комьюнити_имя 
и имея только это надо сделать мониторинг ,интерфейса fa0/0 
на потерю пакетов и загрузку.

Comment: я не прошу что-бы кто-то сделал за меня, я просто на самом деле уже все перелопатил лол могу скрин с историей браузера скинуть
все, что на скрине не верно, это я уже после понял)

Comment: вообщем мне бы просто хотелось 
что-бы объяснили как в zabbix настроить мониторинг интерфейса fa0/0 на коммутаторе на потерю трафа и загруженность интерфейса

Comment: И всё-таки, какое сообщение об ошибке показывает Zabbix?

Comment: ошибка invalid SNMP OID at position 37

Comment: Было бы здорово, если бы Вы всё-таки скопировали текст ошибки.

Comment: В любом случае, если у Вас нет доступа к устройству и есть доступ только к интерфейсу Zabbix, Вы можете воспользоваться функциональностью low-level discovery для SNMP (см. https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery#discovery_of_snmp_oids). Делая обнаружение по ifDescr и подобным деревьям, Вы сможете узнать, какие интерфейсы есть на устройстве, какой из них fa0/0, и затем уже настраивать исходя из полученной информации. Другими словами, Вы можете использовать low-level discovery в Zabbix как замену snmpwalk.

Comment: спасибо большое. теперь знаю куда копать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38844/discussion-between-qaz-qaz-and-asaveljevs).